# IndexError : list index out of range when retrieving text from a file

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a quiz in python, and I need to retrieve more than one question from an external text file.
I manage to retrieve the first question successfully, but I get the "list index out of range" error when trying to retrieve the second one.

This is what a fragment of my current code looks like.

```
if choice1 == "CH":
        choice2 = input ("Would you like to do the easy, medium or hard questions ?").lower()
        if choice2 == "easy":
            load_profile = open("chemistryquiz.txt","r")
            question1 = load_profile.read().splitlines()[4]
            print (question1)
            question2 = load_profile.read().splitlines()[5]
            print (question2)
```

The program works perfectly fine if I comment out anything regarding question 2. Where have I gone wrong ? P.S, I checked the text file and I made sure the number of the line is 5, I am aware you start counting from 0 when programming in python.

Also, these are the contents of chemistryquiz.txt

```
Chemistry Quiz :

Easy :

1) What is the chemical symbol of Carbon ? A: C B: Ca
2) What is the weight of an electron ? A: 0 B: 0.1
```

Comment: Can you share the contents of `chemistryquiz.txt`?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.

Comment: @OSG I suggest you edit that into the question (maybe replacing the expletives?), adding the new lines accordingly.

Comment: Please ignore the profanity, I was filling in the quiz with any words that would come to my mind at the moment since that is only a test and I will edit it later anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thye problem is that you're calling `load_profile.read()` multiple times. Each time you call this, it starts reading from where any previous file reading functions left off. But the first call read the entire file, so the second call has nothing left to read. It returns an empty string, and `splitlines()` returns an empty list.

Just read the file once.

```
lines = load_profile.read().splitlines()
question1 = lines[4]
question2 = lines[5]
```

Comment: Does anyone know the rationale for having `splitlines` treat the empty string specially?

Comment: It's consistent with not adding an empty line at the end if the string ends with newline. It's designed to mirror the way you treat a file as a sequence of lines, which may end with a newline after the last line.

Comment: So `lines = file.read().splitlines()` should return the same list of lines as `lines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in file]`

Comment: It's not obvious to me why iterating over an empty file should not yield an empty string either. But I can see that it's good that these things are consistent.

Comment: Because you're iterating over *lines*. There are no lines in an empty file. It's not the same as file with a single blank line.

Comment: This is why POSIX requires that text files have a newline at the end of all lines, including the last line. Otherwise an empty file is ambiguous: it could be a single blank line or no lines at all.

Answer (score 2):

Let's step through this:

```
load_profile = open("chemistryquiz.txt","r")
```

The file is open; and you have a file handle **load_profile**.
The file bookmark is at the start of the file.

```
question1 = load_profile.read().splitlines()[4]
```

You have read the entire file, split it into lines, and assigned the 5th line to **question1**.

```
print (question1)
question2 = load_profile.read().splitlines()[5]
```

Since the bookmark is still at the end of the file, **read()** returns only EOF.  **splitlines** does nothing useful.  There is no element 5.
*KABOOM!*.

---

Go back to the text on reading lines from a file.  For instance ...

```
with open("chemistryquiz.txt","r") as load_profile:
    for input_line in load_profile:
        # This loop will give you the file, one line at a time.
```